# Windows emulator different results from unity scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, hololens-emulator

I am having a problem with the hololens windows emulator. It is showing different results from the unity scene. In the unity scene we are just making a 3d sphere active and changing its color. However, in the windows emulator our logos are showing but not the sphere.

Answer (score 0):

My guess (with the very limited information) is that one of or a combination of these things are happening:

1. You didn't set up the scene using Unity toolkit and your view in unity is much larger than the actual HoloLens FOV (From the HoloToolkit menu select Apply HoloLens Project Settings)
2. You are using the wrong the camera, you should remove the default camera and add the HoloLensCamera in the Assets/HoloToolkit/Input/Prefabs folder
3. Something you are doing is completely incompatible with HoloLens and therefore works in Unity but not in the emulator, we'll need more info for this.

Check out this tutorial for more info on how to get a project up and running for HoloLens:

http://www.cameronvetter.com/2016/10/25/hololens-tutorial-unity-3d-project-creation/